# Cannot resolve symbol @android:color/white anymore

Tags: android, android-xml, android-color, android-attributes

[image]

But the application is not compiling.

I don't know what can I do?

- I am try to clean project
- I am try build project
- I am restart mac

And so on,but this steps don't help me.
Who can help me?
Thank you

Comment: you can use `android:background="#ffffff"`

Comment: i want know this is why? is can used!! but give me a error tip!.

Comment: Its the best solution to use your own color.xml . @android:color/ can be OS dependent . I have faced same problem recently in some customized OS.

Comment: More Than This!!!  my style have same problem     <style name="Widget.Design.AppBarLayout" parent="android:Widge(red)t">

Comment: post your whole XML file

Comment: post you XML code here

Comment: ![code image](http://img.blog.csdn.net/20171207175128244?watermark/2/text/aHR0cDovL2Jsb2cuY3Nkbi5uZXQvRWFza1NoYXJr/font/5a6L5L2T/fontsize/400/fill/I0JBQkFCMA==/dissolve/70/gravity/SouthEast)

Answer (score 1):

you can give color manually like

```
"#ffffff"
```

or create color in colors file like

```
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
```

and then

```
    android:background="@color/white"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply write this:

```
android:background="#ffffff"
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO!
This has already been answered by someone else, no need to add the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If the resource already exists in colors.xml file, try Invalid Caches / Restart

Comment: this problem is fix already,thank you very much